# angular router navigate and back button issue

Tags: angular

I have this example that consists of several routes:

https://angular-router-basic-example-w6ydu8.stackblitz.io

The app loads the first route which is login, then I have `this.router.navigate(['/catalog'])`, which programatically takes me to another route after 2 seconds - catalog. Inside catalog, when I click the browser's back button, I expect to go back to login, but instead the browser takes me to an empty address bar. Is this behavior normal? What if I want the back button to take me to login?

This is the full code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-w6ydu8

Thanks.

EDIT: this issue happens in Chrome, and strangely, only if I don't click the body of the document before clicking back.

Comment: It takes me back to login

Comment: Takes me back to login aswell. Maybe some browser plugins conflicting?

Comment: Seems like it gets back to `login` in non chromium browsers, and the issue is only in chromium based browsers